# Subgroups of index $p$ in infinite product $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}C_p$

Tags: group-theory

> What are the subgroups of index $p$ in the infinite product $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}C_p$, where $p$ is a fixed prime? Are they all open? If not then which are open?

Here, we endow $C_p$ with discrete topology and $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}C_p$ with the product topology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the open subgroups are exactly the ones with finite indices: at least in the norm topology in CFT it is right, but I have to check the general case: it seems to be too good to be true, though.

Comment: What is $C_p$? Is it $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Is it $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? Where does $n$ come into play? Is it supposed to be $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: In group theory $C_p$ means the cyclic group of order $p$. So the group we are looking at is the product of $\mathbb{N}$ copies of $C_p$.

Comment: This is a nice question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but the question has been around for over ten years now, and the answer does at least show that $G=\prod_{\Bbb N}C_p$ has the maximum possible number of subgroups of index $p$, and that they are by no means all open.

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. For each $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in G$ there is a unique $h_{\mathscr{U}}(x)\in C_p$ such that $\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k=h_{\mathscr{U}}(x)\}\in\mathscr{U}$; it is easy to check that $h_{\mathscr{U}}:G\to C_p$ is a homomorphism and hence that $\ker h_{\mathscr{U}}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $p$. For convenience let $H_\mathscr{U}=\ker h_{\mathscr{U}}$.

If $\mathscr{U}$ is a fixed ultrafilter, then there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that  $\mathscr{U}=\{U\subseteq\Bbb N:n\in U\}$, $h_{\mathscr{U}}(x)=x_n$ for each $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in G$, and $H_\mathscr{U}=\{x\in G:x_n=0\}$, a subbasic open set in the product $G$. (Here I take $C_p$ to be $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with addition modulo $p$.) This yields countably infinitely many open subgroups of $G$ of index $p$.

Now suppose that $\mathscr{U}$ is a free ultrafilter. Let $z_k=0$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$, and let $z=\langle z_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in H_\mathscr{U}$. Suppose that $H_\mathscr{U}$ is open; then there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$\{x\in G:x_k=0\text{ for all }k\le n\}\subseteq H_\mathscr{U}\,,$$

since $\big\{\{x\in G:x_k=0\text{ for all }k\le n\}:n\in\Bbb N\big\}$ is a nbhd base at $z$. But this is clearly false: if for $k\in\Bbb N$ we define

$$x_k=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }k\le n\\
1,&\text{if }k>n
\end{cases}$$

and let $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, then $h_{\mathscr{U}}(x)=1$, and $x\in B\setminus H_\mathscr{U}$. Thus, $H_\mathscr{U}$ is never open when $\mathscr{U}$ is a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$.

If $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ are distinct ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$, fix $U\in\mathscr{U}\setminus\mathscr{V}$, and define $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in G$ by setting

$$x_k=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }k\in U\\
1,&\text{if }k\in\Bbb N\setminus U\,;
\end{cases}$$

then $x\in H_\mathscr{U}\setminus H_\mathscr{V}$, so $H_\mathscr{U}\ne H_\mathscr{V}$. There are $2^{2^\omega}=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ distinct ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$, so we have found $2^{2^\omega}=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ distinct subgroups of $G$ with index $p$, only countably many of which are open in $G$. This is the maximum possible number of subgroups of $G$, since $|G|=2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$, and $G$ therefore has only $2^{2^\omega}=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ subsets.